# Natbib and website citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using the Natbib package and using the apalike style. However, I cannot get the website citation to work as planned. I do know of the option of BibLatex, however, I do not want to use that as I'm relatively new to Latex. I have found suggestions that I use the @Misc entry, but that does not italicize the title of the website, which is what I need.

The best example I could find regarding Natbib and website citations was the following:

```
@Misc{Tho98w,
Author = "Len Thomas",
Title = "Statistical power analysis software",
Note = "http://www.forestry.ubc.ca/conservation/power/",
year = 1998
}
```

However, there are two problems with this entry. (1) the "Statistical power analysis software" is not in italics and it does not have an "accessed [date]" field, which is required.

In summary, I'd like my citation to look like the following (written in Word):

Department of Basic Education. (2010). *Education Statistics in South Africa, 2009*.
Available: http://www.education.gov.za/emis/emisweb/09Stats/DoE%20Statistics%20in%20South%20Africa%202009.pdf
[Accessed 16 April]

Answer (score 16):

Note that it is not the `natbib` package per se that determines the "look and feel" of the entries in the reference section; instead, this is determined by the bibliography style that's in use. The `apalike` bibliography style is more than twenty years old and thus predates the use of entities such as websites. In order to (i) properly reference a webpage with URL information using this bibliography style and (ii) italicize the contents of the `title` field, you'll have to set up your bib entry along the following lines:

```
@Misc{Tho98w,
  Author = "Len Thomas",
  Title  = "\emph{Statistical power analysis software}",
  Note   = "\url{http://www.forestry.ubc.ca/conservation/power/}
           [Accessed: Whenever]",
  year = 1998,
}
```

Note that you'll also need to load either the `url` or the `hyperref` package (in the main `.tex` file) in order to inform LaTeX what to do with the instruction `\url`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I already have the hyperref package loaded in the preamble.