# Is there an alternative to apalike that properly deals with website citations?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using the apalike style suitable for economic papers. This old bibliography style doesn't deal with URLS. An [answer provides a trick using the note field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157293/44254) in the bibtex entry such as:

```
Note   = "\url{http://www.url/}
       [Accessed: Whenever]",
```

Another answer [suggests using a different bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146163/44254) to properly display urls but doesn't provide alternatives. Is there an alternative recommended bibliography style that is a successor of apalike and properly deals with urls?

Comment: What do you mean by 'successor'? There are many APA-related styles. I believe the most complete implementation of APA -- which has rules that are difficult to implement programmatically -- is `biblatex-apa`, which requires you to skip `natbib` and BibTeX and use `biblatex` and Biber instead.

Comment: Thank you @jon skipping bibtex is not an option for me in the short term, I only have 10 days to complete my current work.

Comment: Switching should take all of about an hour: you simply load a different set of packages, change a couple of commands and do `biber myfile.bcf` instead of `bibtex myfile.aux`.  This is not much more involved than loading a different bibliography style. But you can try your luck [CTAN's sup­port for type­set­ting texts re­lat­ing to psy­chol­ogy](https://www.ctan.org/topic/psychology).

Comment: I tried [all psychology styles on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/psychology) none of them renders urls. I use Lyx 2.1.2. [Changing Lyx to biblatex](https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex) will be a little bit complicated but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks @jon for the hint to the CTAN psychology style list, I found my luck on another list of [bibliography styles for economics](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic?lang=en). The `jae` (Journal of Applied Econometrics) style properly supports urls.

Comment: I'm glad because, unfortunately, I do not really know much about LyX.